# Are there specific layers in the subsurface that come before gas or oil?

Tags: seismic, geologic-layers

Currently, I've started working on a geophysics project. More specifically, I'm trying to find gas and oil reservoirs in SEGY files using deep learning. I've been reading about seismic reflection methods and watched a series of lessons at [IRIS Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/IRISEnO), but something isn't very clear to me yet, and this leads to my question. Is there some kind of relationship between two different rock layers? I mean, something along the lines "after a layer of shale it's more likely that I find an oil reservoir than after a layer of limestones".
In summary, what I'd like to know is whether or not there is some kind of "common layer ordering", or pattern, in the subsurface, even though if it's not 100% deterministic.

Comment: it is expected that you do a minimum of research before asking a question here,this is one of the first hits when googling:oil and gas bearing rocks https://www.norskpetroleum.no/en/petroleum-resources/petroleum-formation/ your question is fully answered in the last half of the page.

Comment: Identification of rock formations is the essence of oil and gas exploration. There are people and even companies whose only objective is to identify these layers. They employ seismic testing, test drilling and I expect other techniques I never heard of.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Those are the main two, my Sedimentology lecturer was ex-big oil and she gave us a thorough rundown. Seismic survey to ID targets, drilling to confirm.

Comment: Apparently she over simplified it for students.

Comment: Not a geologist; But three formations are needed; 1- source, 2-reservoir, and 3- cap or seal. For example, shale can be all three; shale is the usual target of fracking to crack it permitting flow of hydrocarbons and water which otherwise may be sealed in the shale